# MYSQL Where Statement first number of figures

Tags: mysql

Can anyone please help me building a where statement for MYSQL in the scenario below?

I have a customer table with many columns one of them being an account number. The first three digits of an account number signify branch code. Now I have a branch with a branch code 235 and I want to query for a list of customer in that branch.

How can I construct where statement that is going to read the first three digits of each account number in the customer’s table and equate it to 235?

Answer (score 1):

cant you just use wildcards to achieve that ?

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename where accnumber like '123%'
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT some_field FROM some_table WHERE LEFT(branch_code, 3)=235`